# Accessing service using istio ingress gives 503 error when mTLS is enabled

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I have a mutual TLS enabled Istio mesh. My setup is as follows

[image]

1. A service running inside a pod (Service container + envoy)
2. An envoy gateway which stays in front of the above service. An Istio Gateway and Virtual Service attached to this. It routes `/info/` route to the above service.
3. Another Istio Gateway configured for ingress using the default istio ingress pod. This also has Gateway+Virtual Service combination. The virtual service directs `/info/` path to the service described in 2

I'm attempting to access the service from the ingress gateway using a curl command such as:

```
$ curl -X GET http://istio-ingressgateway.istio-system:80/info/ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -v
```

But I'm getting a 503 not found error as below:

```
$ curl -X GET http://istio-ingressgateway.istio-system:80/info/ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.105.138.94...
* Connected to istio-ingressgateway.istio-system (10.105.138.94) port 80 (#0)
> GET /info/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer ...
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-length: 57
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Sat, 12 Jan 2019 13:30:13 GMT
< server: envoy
<
* Connection #0 to host istio-ingressgateway.istio-system left intact
```

I checked the logs of `istio-ingressgateway` pod and the following line was logged there

```
[2019-01-13T05:40:16.517Z] "GET /info/ HTTP/1.1" 503 UH 0 19 6 - "10.244.0.5" "curl/7.47.0" "da02fdce-8bb5-90fe-b422-5c74fe28759b" "istio-ingressgateway.istio-system" "-"
```

If I logged into istio ingress pod and attempt to send the request with curl, I get a successful 200 OK.

```
# curl hr--gateway-service.default/info/ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -v
```

Also, I managed to get a successful response for the same curl command when the mesh was created in mTLS disabled mode. There are no conflicts shown in mTLS setup.

Here are the config details for my service mesh in case you need additional info.

**Pods**

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                                       READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
default         hr--gateway-deployment-688986c87c-z9nkh                    1/1       Running     0          37m
default         hr--hr-deployment-596946948d-c89bn                         2/2       Running     0          37m
default         hr--sts-deployment-694d7cff97-gjwdk                        1/1       Running     0          37m
ingress-nginx   default-http-backend-6586bc58b6-8qss6                      1/1       Running     0          42m
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-6bd7c597cb-t4rwq                  1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    grafana-85dbf49c94-lfpbr                                   1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-citadel-545f49c58b-dq5lq                             1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-cleanup-secrets-bh5ws                                0/1       Completed   0          42m
istio-system    istio-egressgateway-7d59954f4-qcnxm                        1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-galley-5b6449c48f-72vkb                              1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-grafana-post-install-lwmsf                           0/1       Completed   0          42m
istio-system    istio-ingressgateway-8455c8c6f7-5khtk                      1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-pilot-58ff4d6647-bct4b                               2/2       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-policy-59685fd869-h7v94                              2/2       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-security-post-install-cqj6k                          0/1       Completed   0          42m
istio-system    istio-sidecar-injector-75b9866679-qg88s                    1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-statsd-prom-bridge-549d687fd9-bspj2                  1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-telemetry-6ccf9ddb96-hxnwv                           2/2       Running     0          42m
istio-system    istio-tracing-7596597bd7-m5pk8                             1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    prometheus-6ffc56584f-4cm5v                                1/1       Running     0          42m
istio-system    servicegraph-5d64b457b4-jttl9                              1/1       Running     0          42m
kube-system     coredns-78fcdf6894-rxw57                                   1/1       Running     0          50m
kube-system     coredns-78fcdf6894-s4bg2                                   1/1       Running     0          50m
kube-system     etcd-ubuntu                                                1/1       Running     0          49m
kube-system     kube-apiserver-ubuntu                                      1/1       Running     0          49m
kube-system     kube-controller-manager-ubuntu                             1/1       Running     0          49m
kube-system     kube-flannel-ds-9nvf9                                      1/1       Running     0          49m
kube-system     kube-proxy-r868m                                           1/1       Running     0          50m
kube-system     kube-scheduler-ubuntu                                      1/1       Running     0          49m
```

**Services**

```
$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                                                                                                                   AGE

default         hr--gateway-service                     ClusterIP      10.100.238.144   <none>         80/TCP,443/TCP                                                                                                            39m
default         hr--hr-service                          ClusterIP      10.96.193.43     <none>         80/TCP                                                                                                                    39m
default         hr--sts-service                         ClusterIP      10.99.54.137     <none>         8080/TCP,8081/TCP,8090/TCP                                                                                                39m
default         kubernetes                              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>         443/TCP                                                                                                                   52m
ingress-nginx   default-http-backend                    ClusterIP      10.109.166.229   <none>         80/TCP                                                                                                                    44m
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx                           NodePort       10.108.9.180     192.168.60.3   80:31001/TCP,443:32315/TCP                                                                                                44m
istio-system    grafana                                 ClusterIP      10.102.141.231   <none>         3000/TCP                                                                                                                  44m
istio-system    istio-citadel                           ClusterIP      10.101.128.187   <none>         8060/TCP,9093/TCP                                                                                                         44m
istio-system    istio-egressgateway                     ClusterIP      10.102.157.204   <none>         80/TCP,443/TCP                                                                                                            44m
istio-system    istio-galley                            ClusterIP      10.96.31.251     <none>         443/TCP,9093/TCP                                                                                                          44m
istio-system    istio-ingressgateway                    LoadBalancer   10.105.138.94    <pending>      80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:31219/TCP,8060:31482/TCP,853:30034/TCP,15030:31544/TCP,15031:32652/TCP   44m
istio-system    istio-pilot                             ClusterIP      10.100.170.73    <none>         15010/TCP,15011/TCP,8080/TCP,9093/TCP                                                                                     44m
istio-system    istio-policy                            ClusterIP      10.104.77.184    <none>         9091/TCP,15004/TCP,9093/TCP                                                                                               44m
istio-system    istio-sidecar-injector                  ClusterIP      10.100.180.152   <none>         443/TCP                                                                                                                   44m
istio-system    istio-statsd-prom-bridge                ClusterIP      10.107.39.50     <none>         9102/TCP,9125/UDP                                                                                                         44m
istio-system    istio-telemetry                         ClusterIP      10.110.55.232    <none>         9091/TCP,15004/TCP,9093/TCP,42422/TCP                                                                                     44m
istio-system    jaeger-agent                            ClusterIP      None             <none>         5775/UDP,6831/UDP,6832/UDP                                                                                                44m
istio-system    jaeger-collector                        ClusterIP      10.102.43.21     <none>         14267/TCP,14268/TCP                                                                                                       44m
istio-system    jaeger-query                            ClusterIP      10.104.182.189   <none>         16686/TCP                                                                                                                 44m
istio-system    prometheus                              ClusterIP      10.100.0.70      <none>         9090/TCP                                                                                                                  44m
istio-system    servicegraph                            ClusterIP      10.97.65.37      <none>         8088/TCP                                                                                                                  44m
istio-system    tracing                                 ClusterIP      10.109.87.118    <none>         80/TCP                                                                                                                    44m
kube-system     kube-dns                                ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>         53/UDP,53/TCP                                                                                                             52m
```

**Gateway and virtual service described in point 2**

```
$ kubectl describe gateways.networking.istio.io hr--gateway
Name:         hr--gateway
Namespace:    default
API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
Kind:         Gateway
Metadata:
  ...
Spec:
  Selector:
    App:                           hr--gateway
  Servers:
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      http2
      Number:    80
      Protocol:  HTTP2
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      https
      Number:    443
      Protocol:  HTTPS
    Tls:
      Mode:  PASSTHROUGH

$ kubectl describe virtualservices.networking.istio.io hr--gateway
Name:         hr--gateway
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app=hr--gateway
              Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
Kind:         VirtualService
Metadata:
  ...
Spec:
  Gateways:
    hr--gateway
  Hosts:
    *
  Http:
    Match:
      Uri:
        Prefix:  /info/
    Rewrite:
      Uri:  /
    Route:
      Destination:
        Host:  hr--hr-service
```

**Gateway and virtual service described in point 3**

```
$ kubectl describe gateways.networking.istio.io ingress-gateway
Name:         ingress-gateway
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"networking.istio.io/v1alpha3","kind":"Gateway","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"ingress-gateway","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"sel...
API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
Kind:         Gateway
Metadata:
  ...
Spec:
  Selector:
    Istio:  ingressgateway
  Servers:
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      http2
      Number:    80
      Protocol:  HTTP2

$ kubectl describe virtualservices.networking.istio.io hr--gateway-ingress-vs
Name:         hr--gateway-ingress-vs
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app=hr--gateway
              API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
Kind:         VirtualService
Metadata:
Spec:
  Gateways:
    ingress-gateway
  Hosts:
    *
  Http:
    Match:
      Uri:
        Prefix:  /info/
    Route:
      Destination:
        Host:  hr--gateway-service
Events:        <none>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is probably as follows: *istio-ingressgateway* initiates mTLS to *hr--gateway-service* on port 80, but *hr--gateway-service* expects plain HTTP connections.

There are multiple solutions:

1. Define a DestinationRule to instruct clients to disable mTLS on calls to *hr--gateway-service*

```
   apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
   kind: DestinationRule
   metadata:
     name: hr--gateway-service-disable-mtls
   spec:
     host: hr--gateway-service.default.svc.cluster.local
     trafficPolicy:
       tls:
         mode: DISABLE
```

2. Instruct *hr-gateway-service* to accept mTLS connections. For that, configure the [server TLS options](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/gateway/#Server-TLSOptions) on port 80 to be `MUTUAL` and to use Istio certificates and the private key. Specify `serverCertificate`, `caCertificates` and `privateKey` to be `/etc/certs/cert-chain.pem`, `/etc/certs/root-cert.pem`, `/etc/certs/key.pem`, respectively.

Comment: Solution 1 works. However, I need to have mTLS between ingress and hr--gateway. So I attempted your second option. It gives me an error `server cannot have TLS settings for plain text HTTP ports` when trying to update the gateway. Can you please suggest why I get that?

Comment: Try to direct the traffic from ingress to hr--gateway thru port 443.

Comment: Hi @Vadim. I changed the virtual service so that the traffic is routed to port 443 of hr--gateway and it worked fine. With this setup can we say the istio mesh is mTLS enabled? What I think is ingress to hr--gateway traffic is https instead of mTLS..

Comment: It is mTLS enabled if you specify `MUTUAL` in the server TLS options of hr--gateway.

Comment: To be on the safe side, see the checks you can perform to ensure mTLS is enabled between the ingress gateway to hr gateway: https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/tasks/security/mutual-tls/

Comment: One more question. Consider this scenario when the application(hr--hr-service) calls envoy (employee--gateway-service) with a curl command. Again this fails with a 503. employee--gateway-service is similar to hr--gateway-service and it routes to employee-employee-service.

Comment: If I explicitly route to port 443 with the curl command I get the expected result. Does this mean I have to change my application code to route to 443 when the mesh is mTLS enabled?  Isn't envoy supposed to handle this without us having to change the code?

Comment: I have a question - why do you need these gateways (hr-gateway and employee-gateway)?

Regarding routing to port 443 - you can specify a VirtualService and rewrite the port by Istio, without changing the application. See an example of port rewriting by a VirtualService https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/egress-tls-origination/#tls-origination-for-egress-traffic.

Comment: I see, it makes sense.